# Need for WAKE LOCK in my new Application if the same is already working through many popular apps working in phone

Tags: android

Do I need to implement WAKE LOCK in my new application if I feel the same is already implemented in many popular applications like GTALK, Whatsapp etc. and those would already working on my target mobile phones.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. What does a `WakeLock` have to do with other applications? Please edit your question to explain in greater detail what your concern is.

Comment: As per my understanding WakeLock (for example PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) prevent CPU to go into sleep. Means it makes awake device not application. If my application needs to run in background and not to be off due to device sleep then WakeLock has to be implemented. My query is that do I need to implement WakeLock separately within my application if whatsapp (assuming this will be running in user device already) like application already implemented this and cpu will not go into sleep.

Comment: If you are wondering why you need a wakelock and some other apps with similar functionality may not, it is likely that they don't actually do much in the background.  GTALK for example probably uses the same underlying functionality as Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) - though perhaps to a degree not available to a 3rd party developer.

Comment: @Chris GCM service can be used by 3rd party developer using Google API credentials and plugin. Here I don't want to use their service but wanted to understand why need to implement duplicate WakeLock in my application if I feel (not confirm) that those service already implemented WakeLock and prevent device to go into sleep mode. which is also my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe WakeLock ( for example PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) prevent CPU to go into sleep. Means it makes awake device not application. If my application need to run in background and not to be off due to device sleep then WakeLock has to be implemented.

Correct. And other applications may also elect to use wakelocks. However, they will use wakelocks when *they* want to, which may not be when *you* want to. You only use a wakelock for a small piece of code where you need to keep the device awake, and you should not be assuming that anyone else happens to hold a wakelock when you need to run that small piece of code.

Comment: Thanks. It clarified me to some extend. One more thing wanted to know that do GTalk and whatsapp like applications (which continuously remain in touch with server and gets push notification) implement temporary WakeLock for small period or for Always/Forever .

Comment: @user3574669: They are hopefully using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).

Comment: Hopefully not sure. fine. For my better clarity can I understand that if those apps wouldn't use GCM but use WakeLock for always then I could leave duplicate WakeLock implementation in my application.